# Label is clipped in the bottom when wrapped into inline-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need a text to be clipped with ellipsis when it doesn't fit into table cell. I have solution for it, but seems to be it has an issue with Bootstrap's Label component. Please see below code:

```
<table class="table commits-table" style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid #777">
    <tr>
        <td class="message">
            <span>
                <!-- This label is clipping in the bottom -->
                <a class="label label-info">Sample</a>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
        </td>
        <td class="date">2015-02-02</td>
        <td class="hash">7482ab63</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
.commits-table .date, .commits-table .hash {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1%;
}

.commits-table .message {
    max-width: 250px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.commits-table .message > span {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block; /* This inline-block cause the issue */
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4269/)

Is anyone have suggestions how to fix Label clip in the bottom in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify; you want to stick the 'sample' to the bottom of the tr?

Comment: I would rather say that I want to achieve layout as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4275/) (aligned with text, without extra space on top), but yet text-overflow to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with the height of the table-cells. have a look http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4273/

increasing the `line-height` will do.

Comment: Is there any other solution possible that fixes Label alignment only?

Comment: you have to atleast increase the line-height of the anchor tag which holds the label.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is the only solution. I also able to work-around it with padding-bottom for span (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4346/)).